# Debugging/profiling/optimizing C# Windows service in VS 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework, windows-services

I am creating a Windows service in C#.  Its purpose is to consume info from a feed on the Internet.  I get the data by using zeromq's pub/sub architecture (my service is a subscriber only).  To debug the service I "host" it in a WPF control panel.  This allows me to start, run, and stop the service without having to install it.  The problem I am seeing is that when I call my stop method it appears as though the service continues to write to the database.  I know this because I put a `Debug.WriteLine()` where the writing occurs.

### More info on the service:

I am attempting to construct my service in a fashion that allows it to write to the database asynchronously.  This is accomplished by using a combination of threads and the ThreadPool.

```
public void StartDataReceiver() // Entry point to service from WPF host
{
    // setup zmq subscriber socket

    receiverThread = new Tread(SpawnReceivers);
    receiverThread.Start();
}

internal void SpawnReceivers()
{
    while(!stopEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessReceivedData), subscriber.Recv()); // subscriber.Recv() blocks when there is no data to receive (according to the zmq docs) so this loop should remain under control, and threads only created in the pool when there is data to process.
    }
}

internal void ProcessReceivedData(Object recvdData)
{
    // cast recvdData from object -> byte[]
    // convert byte[] -> JSON string
    // deserialize JSON -> MyData

    using (MyDataEntities context = new MyDataEntities())
    {
        // build up EF model object

        Debug.WriteLine("Write obj to db...");
        context.MyDatas.Add(myEFModel);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

internal void QData(Object recvdData)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Queued obj in queue...");
    q.Enqueue((byte[])recvdData);
}

public void StopDataReceiver()
{
    stopEvent.Set();
    receiverThread.Join();
    subscriber.Dispose();
    zmqContext.Dispose();
    stopEvent.Reset();
}
```

The above code are the methods that I am concerned with.  When I debug the WPF host, and the method `ProcessReceivedData` is set to be queued in the thread pool everything seems to work as expected, until I stop the service by calling `StopDataReceiver`. As far as I can tell the thread pool never queues any more threads (I checked this by placing a break point on that line), but I continue to see "Write obj to db..." in the output window and when I 'Break All' in the debugger a little green arrow appears on the `context.SaveChanges();` line indicating that is where execution is currently halted.  When I test some more, and have the thread pool queue up the method `QData` everything seems to work as expected.  I see "Queued obj in queue..." messages in the output window until I stop the service. Once I do no more messages in the output window.

**TL;DR:**

I don't know how to determine if the Entity Framework is just slowing things way down and the messages I am seeing are just the thread pool clearing its backlog of work items, or if there is something larger at play.  How do I go about solving something like this?

Would a better solution be to queue the incoming JSON strings as byte[] like I do in the `QData` method then have the thread pool queue up a different method to work on clearing the queue.  I feel that that solution will only shift the problem around and not actually solve it.

Could another solution be to write a new service dedicated to clearing that queue?  The problem I see with writing another service would be that I would probably have to use WCF (or possibly zmq) to communicate between the two services which would obviously add overhead and possibly become less performant.

I see the critical section in all of this being the part of getting the data off the wire fast enough because the publisher I am subscribed to is set to begin discarding messages if my subscriber can't keep up.

Comment: You probably have outstanding callbacks you queued using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. Even though you stopped some of the threads the threads for the callbacks are still arrive and when the data comes in they `ProcessReceivedData`

Comment: @Pawel: I'm not sure I understand you. Are you saying that even though I have stopped queueing work items, there are still some left?  Because the `Recv()` method on the socket should be blocking when there is no data.  Which would mean that work items don't get queued unless there is something to do.

Comment: my feeling is that when you stopped queuing work items there were already some in the queue for which requests have been sent. These work items receive responses and they process what they received. Even though recv() is blocking you basically have many work items blocked on the recv() which wake up when recv() unblocks.

Comment: I have been using the network monitor found in the Window stask manager and the traffic goes to zero when I stop the service. So it must just be EF taking a long time to write out the changes.